# Can the Image path for the AddImage method in MigraDoc be used for the Visual Studio project subfolders?

Tags: pdf, migradoc

The following example shows a very simple construction for creating a PDF with MigraDoc. The most parts of it are taken from the examples provided in the MigraDoc - Wiki documentation.

I have commented all the most few steps for the job. The path for the "AddImage" points to the subfolder "Images" which is a subfolder of the folder "Resources" created in the root of the console application of a Visual Studio (VS) project.

The most recent MigraDoc library is added to the VS - project via "NuGet" just yesterday.

The application creates the PDF output file unfortunately without the provided image file, if it is used in another machine. Because the execution file has then no access to the subfolders created in VS project.

Is there any solution to this problem?

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Create a MigraDoc document
        var document = new Document();

        // Add a section the document
        var section = document.AddSection();

        // .....


        /*
        ------------------------------- NOTE -------------------------------
        The path "../../Resources/Images/MigraDoc.png" is valid only for the developer machine!
        A copy of the content of the "Debug" or "Release" folder any where else does not show the image in the output PDF.
        Because such a copy has no access to the subfolder "/Resources/Images" of the Visual Studio project on the developer machine.
        */
        section.Headers.Primary.AddImage("../../Resources/Images/MigraDoc.png");

        // Create a renderer for PDF that uses Unicode font encoding.
        var pdfRenderer = new PdfDocumentRenderer(true);

        // Set the MigraDoc document.
        pdfRenderer.Document = document;

        // Create the PDF document.
        pdfRenderer.RenderDocument();

        // Save the PDF document...
        var filename = "Invoice.pdf";

        // Create the output directory
        Directory.CreateDirectory("PDF");

        // Create the ouptput file path
        var savePath = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location) + "\\PDF\\" + filename;

        // Delete the output file if it already exists
        if (File.Exists(savePath))
            File.Delete(savePath);

        // Save the output file
        pdfRenderer.Save(savePath);

        // Start a the default PDF viewer from the operation system
        Process.Start(savePath);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A path beginning with `..\..\` relies on the current directory. For a portable solution, include the images you need in your deployment.

Recommended usage: The MigraDoc `Document` class has an `ImagePath` property. If your installation folder has an `Images` folder, just locate your .EXE file and set the ImagePath property accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the reply!
The images cannot be deployed in the application deployment subfolders because of two reasons:

1- There are some hundreds of MB images in use and in such case they then exist twice (one set in subfolder of the VS - project and the other one in "Images" subfolder of the application deployment).

2- Security and integrity of the application does not allow such deployment.

Unfortunately, the installation folder has no chance to have an "Images" folder.
Any suggestion for a solution is highly appreciated.

Comment: You cannot add images to the document that are not available on the computer where the application runs. You can add them as resources to any DLL, but then you still have the size problem. Maybe the subfolder of the VS project is the wrong place for the images - unless you want to run the app only on computers that can access the VS project folder. Consider coming up with a deployment concept that is actually doable.